# How can I display FTP details in a listview without including the password?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a simple file moving/duplicating program that needs to have FTP capabilities, so I have to keep a list of all the FTP details to send files to. This list needs to be displayed for the sake of adding/removing elements to it via the UI, so I have been trying to find ways to display only the location in a listview.

Previously, I tried to have a dictionary that would contain the location as the key, and the user/password as the value, and only display the value, but this is not ideal as dictionaries don't bind very nicely with listviews, and don't raise an event when a new item is added.
My second idea was to have a list of `FtpWebRequest`s, but the `ToString()` method of that just seems to print "System.Net.FtpWebRequest" instead of any of the information in the object, which seems quite pointless.

Is there a method I'm missing, or a better way to implement either of the methods I've tried?

Comment: I can't understand what's the role of FTP in the question. Isn't the question about showing some columns of a `List<T>` in a `ListView` or `DataGridView`?

Comment: I don't mind how the data is stored, but I need to be able to hold on to the password somewhere without displaying it in the UI. It just needs to appropriately hold the FTP info and also interface with the listview.

Comment: A `ListView` or `DataGridView` is just a `View`. It will show a `Model`. You can decide what to show. For example, I suppose you have a `Model` class containing `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3` and you want to hide `Property3` in `DataGridView`.

Comment: Then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the `DataGridView` to show refreshed data when some property changes. Also keep data in a `BindingList<Model>` and assign data to `DataSource` of `DataGridView` so if you add or remove records the `DataGridView` will be notified of changes. Also decorate `Property3` with `[Browsable(false)]` attribute, so the `Property3` will not be shown in `DataGridView` by default. You can add/remove columns and set column types based on your requirement.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying I need to make a custom `Model` class to store the FTP information and be able to choose how it's displayed, and to put it in a `BindingList<Model>` to pass to the `ListView` (because I don't think a `DataGridView` is appropriate here)? Seems a bit heavy to me but I'll use it.

Comment: If you don't want to create a custom model, you can rely on `DataTable`. Also I believe a `DataGridView` is always better than a `ListView` for showing a list. `DataGridView` has data-binding support while `ListView` doesn't have. You can edit cells in `DataGridView` while you can not do the same with `ListView`.

Comment: I thought a `ListView` did have data binding support, unless I've been misunderstanding what I've tried to do by giving it a `DataSource`. As for editing cells, I'm not sure that's totally useful here since you'd need to be able to edit the password but I don't want to show that. I'm reaching the point where the hassle outweighs the benefits, and I'm considering making this a command-line program that reads in from JSON configs instead.

Comment: Using `DataTable` it's just: `var dt = new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add("C1"); dt.Columns.Add("C2"); dt.Rows.Add("x","xx"); dt.Rows.Add("y","yy"); dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; dataGridView1.Columns["C2"].Visible = false;`